# how to read the variable *(int*)x?

Tags: c

I got this from a site which was explaining sorting. But i could not understand `*(int*)x`.  How to read the variable x when used like this in C program? Is it pointer to pointer of x or is it different? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Jon Useless advice since this is no declaration...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get there if you split it up, first:

```
(int*)x
```

This casts `x` to an `int*`, pointer to an `int`. I assume in this case, `x` is an `int`, so the number in `x` gets interpreted as a pointer.

In the next step:

```
*(int*)x
```

`*` dereferences a pointer, in this case the just casted `int`. The result is an `int`.

In short: Interpret an `int` as a pointer and get the value it points to.

Comment: The statement "Interpret an int as a pointer and get the value it points to." is a bit misleading, since you don't know the original type of `x`.

Comment: That's why I stated that I assume `x` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

You cast `x` to an integer pointer first and then you dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about `*` in C like this:

- with types (e.g., `int`) it means **pointer**
- with values (e.g., `x`) it means **dereferencing**

So:

- `(int*)x` is a pointer to `int`
- `*y` is a value from the memory addres pointed to by `y`

Answer (score 0):

Same answer as others with a different explanation.
Try to interpret this -
int* ptr = (int*)x;
int y = *ptr;